# How to read variable separated by punctuations in a text file in C

Tags: c, file-io, binary-search-tree, read-write

I was wondering how to read data from a text file that has its data separated by a comma.

For example line 1 of the text file says: `(Integer,Name Surname, IntegerArray)`

This is 1 line: `123456789,Jonh Brown,123456434-4325234-235234-42345234`

```
typedef struct BST
{
    long long ID;
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    long long *friendsID;
    struct BST *left;
    struct BST *right;
}BST;
```

reading from file:

```
do
{
    c = fscanf(fp,"%I64d%*c%s%s",&ID,name,surname);
    if (c != EOF)
        root=insertNewUser(root,ID,name,surname);
} while (c != EOF);

newNodeTemp->ID = ID;
newNodeTemp->name = (char*)calloc(strlen(name),sizeof(char));
newNodeTemp->surname = (char*)calloc(strlen(surname),sizeof(char));
strcpy(newNodeTemp->name,name);
strcpy(newNodeTemp->surname,surname);
```

but I do not know how to get it as array into BST->friends without `'-'`(hyphen).

this part: `123456434-4325234-235234-42345234`

I defined the friends of array as a pointer. Because we don't know its size. I will use dynamic memory allocation...

Comment: You probably want to use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/). You can use it to convert the string read from the file to an array.

Comment: That is called a "comma separated variable" file, or CSV, and there are plenty of references both on google and stackoverflow.

Comment: The answer depends on whether you need to account for "empty fields" (e.g. `some,values,,can,be,empty`). If you do NOT need to handle empty fields, `strtok` is fine, if you do, then `strsep` is the function to use. In either case, you can always walk a pointer down the line an pick out fields as your go.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I was thinking the question was specifically about the `friendsID` field, but I could be wrong. Either way good info.

Comment: I think you are right, so you would need to nest `strtok` within calls to `strtok_r` to separate tokens, then friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, that you have a CSV with user info and the friends of that user, where the friends are encoded as a hyphen separated list of friend-IDs as the third field in the line, then you can use a combination of the re-entrant version of `strtok` (named `strtok_r`) to separate the comma separated fields, and than use calls to `strtok` within your outer loop to separate the hyphen separated values.

Note, `strtok_r` requires an additional "*save pointer*" as its third argument so that you can resume calls to that instance of `strtok_r` after having made intermediate calls to a difference instance of `strtok` or `strtok_r` for alternative separation purposes.

Given your line of:

```
"123456789,Jonh Brown,123456434-4325234-235234-42345234"
```

where `123456789` is the ID, `Jonh Brown` is the name, and `123456434-4325234-235234-42345234` is a list of friend IDs, you could parse the line and individual friends, just by keeping a field count and calling a separate instance of `strtok` within your tokinzation loop to separate friends on hyphens.

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FRIENDS 3

int main (void) {

    char line[] = "123456789,Jonh Brown,123456434-4325234-235234-42345234",
        *delims = ",\n",    /* strtok_r delimiters for tokens */
        *p      = line,     /* pointer to line */
        *sp     = p;        /* save pointer for reentrant strtok_r */
    int count = 0;

    /* must use reentrant version of strtok to nest strtok use for friends */
    p = strtok_r (line, delims, &sp);  /* 1st call uses name of buffer */
    count++;

    while (p) {             /* outputer tokenization loop */
        printf ("token: '%s'\n", p);
        if (count == FRIENDS) {
            char *pf = calloc (strlen (p) + 1, 1),  /* pointer to friends   */
                *delim2 = "-\n",                    /* delims for friends   */
                *f;                                 /* pointer preserves pf */
            if (!pf) {
                perror ("malloc-pf");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            strcpy (pf, p);                 /* copy friends token to pf */
            f = pf;                         /* set f, to pf, to preserve pf */
            f = strtok (f, delim2);         /* regular strtok OK for friends */
            if (f)
                printf ("friends:\n");
            while (f) {     /* friends tokenization loop */
                printf ("    %s\n", f);
                f = strtok (NULL, delim2);  /* subsequent calls use NULL */
            }
            free (pf);      /* free allocated memory at preserved address */
            count = 0;      /* reset count */
        }
        p = strtok_r (NULL, delims, &sp);  /* subsequent calls use NULL */
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** since `strtok` modifies the original string and advances the pointer it uses, you must make a copy of the friends token, and preserve a pointer to the starting address of the allocated token for friends (`pf`) so that it can be freed after you are done with separating friends)

(**also note:** if your system provides `strdup`, you can replace the two `calloc (strlen (p) + 1, 1)` and `strcpy (pf, p);` calls with a simple call to `char *pf = strdup(p);`. But note, since `strdup` allocates dynamically, you should still validate `if (!pf)` after the call)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtok_csv
token: '123456789'
token: 'Jonh Brown'
token: '123456434-4325234-235234-42345234'
friends:
    123456434
    4325234
    235234
    42345234
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I like your reply, thank you. I've finished my code. If I have a question, i do.

Comment: Sure, just post it as a comment below and I'm happy to help you further.

Comment: If your question is about your choice to dynamically allocate for your unknown number of friends -- that is the correct way to go. (if they don't exceed the range of `int` (or `long`), it may make sense to convert them to numbers with `strtol`, etc..

Comment: `do
    {
        token = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
        newNodeTemp->friendsID[i]=atoll(token);
        i++;
    }while(token != NULL);` Thank you I used `atoll` @david